# How to store SSIS Packages duration

Tags: ssis, package, duration

I need to store the duration of running SSIS packages until execution into SQL database. How can I calculate it.

Comment: Help me understand what you are attempting to do. Your comment on Ferdipux's answer about "achieving this with Visual Studio" has me perplexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2012+, you are definitely urged to use SSIS Catalogs (SSISDB). Main reason for that - new extensive package logging execution system. View [catalog.executions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878089.aspx) contains necessary for your task data.
If you are on SQL 2008 or run packages out of SSIS Catalogs - then you have to craft something on your side. You might parse results output of DTExec - it always reports runtime duration.

Comment: No I'm using SQL 2012, is that mean I have to export them to SSIS Catalogs otherwise there are no way it can be achieved with Visual Studio?

Comment: @Tony, you are right, you have to deploy projects and packages to SSIS Catalogs. Visual Studio has little to do with your original task - standard SSMS report _All Executions_ outputs runtime duration, and _Performance_ report for specific package shows small analysis on last 10 package execution duration.